# Any data on Big Sur market share?

Tags: big-sur

Update: I can't answer as the question is closed (interesting enough I have received a badge for the popular question for the question that was closed). But I have found new info that Big Sur doesn't send to the web sites in UserArgent that it is the version 11.00 as Apple expected problems with web site compatibility. As such there can't be any data originated from the web sites and as most currently published data originates from that source it is likely that there won't be any data on this.

I can't find any data on Big Sur market share among Mac versions.

The only source that covers this is https://gs.statcounter.com/macos-version-market-share/desktop/worldwide

However on that source there is no data for Big Sur - if you download .csv you will see that all values add up to 100% and there is no 'Big Sur' or 'Other' category. I would assume that Big Sur has similar to what Catalina had in this period of year (41%) and that all other values should be corrected by multiplying with 59%.

But that is just a guess. Does anyone have any data? Including from his own site if nothing else just if it has at least 1k Mac users a month?

Comment: Although I've closed this question (since it doesn't fall within the scope of our site), I've posted an answer more for your info. Hopefully this helps to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience data for macOS adoption (as opposed to iOS) is fraught with inconsistencies. Many sources just lump the different versions of macOS together in the one bucket. Others even lump macOS and iOS together in the same bucket. In some cases, the data is based on web traffic which is also fraught with difficulty (as the same version of browser can be installed on multiple versions of macOS).

One thing to keep in mind is the sale of new Mac hardware will include the latest version of macOS (e.g. the M1 Macs all come with macOS Big Sur pre-installed, etc).

The last figure<sup>1</sup> I recall seeing of new Mac sales was  for the three month period ended 26 December 2020 (8,675,000 Macs, a big jump attributed mainly to M1 Macs). However, many new Mac sales occurred prior to the release of macOS Big Sur or the release of M1 Macs, so that figure will be a mixture of macOS Catalina and macOS Big Sur.

However, the reason I mention Mac sales figures is because your post asks at the end about macOS Big Sur having *"at least 1k Mac users a month"* - which of course is well and truly below the millions it will be based on those sales figures.

In any case, over time sites like [statcounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/macos-version-market-share/desktop/worldwide) (which you've already referenced) and [statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/944559/worldwide-macos-version-market-share/) will include the latest version of macOS in their charts etc. And for most people, that is all they can really wait for or rely on in terms of these figures.

<sup>1 [Condensed Consolidated Statements of Operations](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/pdfs/FY21%20Q1%20Consolidated%20Financial%20Statements.pdf), Apple, 27 January 2021.</sup>

Comment: I clearly said the web site that has 1k Mac visitors a month, not what you mention here.

Comment: It's 2023 and statscounter and statista still seem to only be including macOS versions up until Catalina...

I suspect this is because they don't care too much and because macOS 10+ versions still report themselves version "10" in the user-agent. (But you can still get the proper macOS version by looking at other components)